# Attended Transfer to gxw410x sip trunk Failed

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I have an issue making an attended transfer to fxo gateway (grand stream gxw4108).

I am using feature code (*2) to commit in call attended transfer.

Call first is initiated and then transfer terminated just when the external pstn phone ring.
Blind transfer is working fine , attended transfer is working fine internally but this issue appears only when transferring to the gxw4108 gateway.

here my configuration(sip.conf):

```
[gxw410x]
host= 192.168.10.239
type=peer
insecure=very
```

i am using elastix version 2.4
and this is sniffing for the traffic: (192.168.10.231: Asterisk   , 192.168.10.239: gxw4108)

```
INVITE sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

Max-Forwards: 70

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>

Contact: <sip:100@192.168.10.231:5060>

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 INVITE

User-Agent: FPBX-2.8.1(1.8.20.0)

Date: Sat, 10 May 2014 20:52:01 GMT

Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH

Supported: replaces, timer

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 288



v=0

o=root 2108910474 2108910474 IN IP4 192.168.10.231

s=Asterisk PBX 1.8.20.0

c=IN IP4 192.168.10.231

t=0 0

m=audio 15580 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 101

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-16

a=ptime:20

a=sendrecv

SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 INVITE

User-Agent: Grandstream GXW4108 (HW 2.0, Ch:7) 1.3.4.13

Content-Length: 0



SIP/2.0 180 Ringing

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>;tag=27454245bd077ea3

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 INVITE

User-Agent: Grandstream GXW4108 (HW 2.0, Ch:7) 1.3.4.13

Contact: <sip:gxw410x@192.168.10.239:5074;transport=udp>

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,NOTIFY,REFER,OPTIONS,INFO,SUBSCRIBE,UPDATE,PRACK

Content-Length: 0



CANCEL sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

Max-Forwards: 70

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 CANCEL

User-Agent: FPBX-2.8.1(1.8.20.0)

Content-Length: 0



SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>;tag=27454245bd077ea3

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 CANCEL

User-Agent: Grandstream GXW4108 (HW 2.0, Ch:7) 1.3.4.13

Supported: replaces, timer, 100rel, path

Content-Length: 0



SIP/2.0 487 Request Cancelled

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>;tag=27454245bd077ea3

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 INVITE

User-Agent: Grandstream GXW4108 (HW 2.0, Ch:7) 1.3.4.13

Content-Length: 0



ACK sip:gxw410x@192.168.10.239:5074;transport=udp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5c0ae243;rport

Max-Forwards: 70

From: "100" <sip:100@192.168.10.231>;tag=as1973acc2

To: <sip:991xxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.10.239>;tag=27454245bd077ea3

Contact: <sip:100@192.168.10.231:5060>

Call-ID: 21f5e75c5c575af45b939d0f349a40fc@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 ACK

User-Agent: FPBX-2.8.1(1.8.20.0)

Content-Length: 0



OPTIONS sip:gxw410x@192.168.10.239:5074;transport=udp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK4b3e2af1;rport

Max-Forwards: 70

From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@192.168.10.231>;tag=as7aaf1080

To: <sip:gxw410x@192.168.10.239:5074;transport=udp>

Contact: <sip:Unknown@192.168.10.231:5060>

Call-ID: 12a9092b47984994709a95bd75d8c60b@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 OPTIONS

User-Agent: FPBX-2.8.1(1.8.20.0)

Date: Sat, 10 May 2014 20:52:18 GMT

Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH

Supported: replaces, timer

Content-Length: 0



SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.231:5060;branch=z9hG4bK4b3e2af1;rport

From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@192.168.10.231>;tag=as7aaf1080

To: <sip:gxw410x@192.168.10.239:5074;transport=udp>;tag=as2cee3cf7

Call-ID: 12a9092b47984994709a95bd75d8c60b@192.168.10.231:5060

CSeq: 102 OPTIONS

User-Agent: Grandstream GXW4108 (HW 2.0, Ch:15) 1.3.4.13

Contact: <sip:gxw410x@192.168.10.239:5074;transport=udp>

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,NOTIFY,REFER,OPTIONS,INFO,SUBSCRIBE,UPDATE,PRACK

Supported: replaces, timer, 100rel, path

Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: I don't know why people is voting -1 for this question ?!!! at least i wanna know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Found the Solution to this issue sharing it may help somebody:
Cause: 
Attended transfer time out which is by default = 15 secs and this time is not enough to establish call to gxw4108 and then gxw4108 establish call to PSTN.
So after 15 secs asterisk sends Cancel Request to terminate the transfer.

Solution: 
Increase Time out by setting value `atxfernoanswertimeout = 60`
 in `/etc/asterisk/features.conf`